# Compute all the local extremepoints of a function using fminunc

Tags: matlab

So I want to compute the lokal extremas for the function

[image]

I used [this link](https://se.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html?searchHighlight=fminunc&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) to help me out. Here is what I've done:

```
options = optimset('Display','off');    

[min1,fval1]=fminunc(@(x)(sin(x(1)+x(2))+3*(x(1)-x(2)/2)^2)*exp(-(x(1)^2+x(2)^2)),[0;-1],options
[min2,fval2]=fminunc(@(x)(sin(x(1)+x(2))+3*(x(1)-x(2)/2)^2)*exp(-(x(1)^2+x(2)^2)),[1.18;2.3],options)

[max1,fval3]=fminunc(@(x)-(sin(x(1)+x(2))+3*(x(1)-x(2)/2)^2)*exp(-(x(1)^2+x(2)^2)),[1;0],options)
[max2,fval4]=fminunc(@(x)-(sin(x(1)+x(2))+3*(x(1)-x(2)/2)^2)*exp(-(x(1)^2+x(2)^2)),[2.3;1.18],options)

format long g
```

The points `p1, p2, p3` and `p4` were obtained from [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=stationary%20points%20(sin(x%2By)%2B3*(x-1%2F2*y)%5E2)*exp(-((x)%5E2%2B(y)%5E2))).

The output in the command window is this:

```
min1 =
      -0.3032
      -0.5316
fval1 =
     -0.50675

min2 =
       1.1773
       2.2344
fval2 =
  -0.00043457

max1 =
      0.91017
     -0.29929
fval3 =
      -1.5746

max2 =
     -0.80798
      0.61241
fval4 =
      -1.2629
```

**Questions:**

1. For `min2` I have `fval2 = -0.00043457`, which is correct. But I want it to say `fval2 = -0.0004`, how can I do this?
2. For `max1` and `max2`, I just made the entire function negative and then applied `fminunc`. This gave me correct (x,y)-koordinates of the respective maxima but the value at these points are given with opposite signs. How can I make Matlab give me `fval3` and `fval4` as positive?

Comment: Do you want all the stationary points? or the local extremas only?

Comment: To begin with, minimization will not find maxima (or hyperbolic points) without transforming the objective function. And second, simply putting an initial guess near a potential minimum does not guarantee that the solver will converge on that point.

Comment: @SardarUsama - I want to find only the local extrempoints.

Comment: then make the correction in your question

Comment: @horchler - I don't understand how I should transform the function and why I need to do so?

Comment: @SardarUsama - Done!

Comment: I updated my question, I hope this makes it easier for anyone to help me. I'm almost done it's just those two details left.

Comment: Do ***NOT*** change the question after you have received working answers. Instead, mark the answer that worked for you as accepted and if you have a new question, ask a new question. Don't invalidate existing answers, as that's a slap in the face of their effort and you come across like a help-vampire.

Comment: I will think about this in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I've rolled back the question since the edited version was inconsistent with the the code you've posted and the variable names you've used in the questions at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results from your Matlab script and Wolfrom are identical for `p1` and `p2` as they are minimums. (Once again see the Wolfram page)

For maximums, I found the problem. Your code is ok. Only the initial guesses should be better determined for `p3` and `p4`. Use your own code but with these guesses for 3rd and 4th function:

```
h=@(x) -(sin(x(1)+x(2))+3*(x(1)-x(2)/2)^2)*exp(-(x(1)^2+x(2)^2));
[max1,fval3]=fminunc(h,[-1;1]);
[max2,fval4]=fminunc(h,[1;-0.3]);
```

However, I recommend you another method for finding local extermas: Find where the derivative of the function with respect to `x` and `y` is zero.

Q1: Use `round()` function to round it.

Q2: The answers Matlab displayed for this script are exactly identical to the Wolfram.

```
max1 =

        -0.807979637093575
         0.612410258594483

max2 =

         0.910173217929548
        -0.299286619005528
```

Q3: Use `x=fminunc(...);` instead of `[x,fval]=fminunc(...);` to omit `fval`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I'm well aware of the fact that fminunc is a function only for finding minimas only but this is what I'm only supposed to use. I suspect that the trick of yours would do the trick but when I try it I get the wrong maximas. Is this how you mean?

 `[max1,fval3] = fminunc(@(x) 1/((sin(x(1) + x(2)) + 3*(x(1) - x(2)/2)^2) * exp(-(x(1)^2 + x(2)^2))),[1;-0.5], options) \\
[max2,fval4] = fminunc(@(x) 1/((sin(x(1) + x(2)) + 3*(x(1) - x(2)/2)^2) * exp(-(x(1)^2 + x(2)^2))),[-1;0.5], options)`

Comment: @Parseval I once again looked at your script and edited my answer. It is easy and accurate.

Comment: This answer doesn't solve any part of the question. Neither Q1 nor Q2

Comment: @SardarUsama It did answer Q2 but not Q1. I added Q1. Thank you.

Comment: No it didn't, the second question asks about the negative signs. Your answer doesn't answer that at all.

Comment: @Parseval About Q3: If you use `max1=fminunc(h,[-1;1]);` instead of  `[max1,fval]=fminunc(h,[-1;1]);` it won't display fval.

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar I've done what you suggested, howver now I only get the x-y points for the min's and max's. I also want to get the functionvalue at these points in z-direction. How can I do this?

Comment: @Parseval If you use the function handle `f` (i.e. `f=@(x) (sin(x(1)+x(2))+3*(x(1)-x(2)/2)^2)*exp(-(x(1)^2+x(2)^2));)` then you can easily assign values to it like this: `f([1,2])` for instance.

Comment: That is exactly what I've tried but I get the error "too many input arguments".

Comment: I was hasty, because you should enter it like this: `f([1,2])` I edited my last comment sorry for that. @Parseval

Comment: Okay, thank you, this worked, but isn't this quite an ineffective method since I have to enter the value myself? I want it to compute the functionvalue without me having to manually do it. This script should work even if I change function.

Comment: Then you may type something like `display(f(min1));` @Parseval

Answer (score 3):

1. If you want to [round](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) `fval2` to 4 decimal places, use `round(fval2,4)`. If you don't want to round and simply want to display `fval2` till 4 decimal places, use [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) i.e. `sprintf('%.4f',fval2)`.
   Note that you are getting that many digits in the first place since you've changed the [format](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html). To reset it to default, enter `format` or `format short`.
2. You are meant to negate your objective function and calculate minimas of the negated function.  These minimas are actually maximas of the original function but `fval3` and `fval4` are internally calculated by putting them in the negated function and hence you get the negative sign. Simply negate them again or evaluate your original function on the maximas.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Sardar. I've edited my code and output. I do have correct answers among the outputs but I wan't to make things cleaner. How can I remove all the `fval`-entries?

Comment: @Parseval In your edited post, you have only one `fval` variable at the end.  Do you want to clear that from memory? then you'd simply do `clear fval`. What do you mean by entries? Or all you need are semi-colons `;` at the end of the lines?

Comment: My apologies I copied the wrong code. What I meant was that I don't want the `fval`-values to be visible in the command window when I run the script. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Parseval Do you want `min1`, `min2` etc to be visible?

Comment: Yes, I only want to remove the `fval`'s

Comment: @Parseval There is no way of suppressing one of the outputs. You can suppress both by adding a semi-colon at the end of the lines and then display only the wanted ones. You can use `disp` or `display` for the displaying purposes or just enter the variable name (without semi-colon which is what display does internally).